# column count in visual force page pdf

Tags: visualforce, controller, pdf

Can any on help me out how to get the column count in a visual force page which is in a PDF format .

```
ProductName            Q1       Q2   Q3    Q4       Total
BXRC-25e4000-F-04      100     200   300   400       1000   
BXRC-25e4000-F-23      200                 200       400
Subtotal ------------  300     200   300   600       1400
```

With Code i could get the Total but the subtotal is not getting calculated correctly.Any help very much appreciated.

VF CODE :

```
<tr class="foot">
     <tr>
         <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-data" >SubTotal :</td> 
         <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity },<br/>
             ${!subtotalofAmount },<br/></td> 
         <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity },<br/>
             ${!subtotalofAmount },<br/></td>
         <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity },<br/>
             ${!subtotalofAmount },<br/></td>
         <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity },<br/>
             ${!subtotalofAmount },<br/></td>  
    </tr> </tr>
```

Code :

```
    public with sharing class QuoteContentController {

      public Map<String,Decimal> PartMap{get;set;}

     //   public Map<String,Decimal> PartMapQuantity{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Quarter1{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Quarter2{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Quarter3{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Quarter4{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Amount1{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Amount2{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Amount3{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Amount4{get;set;}

       public Competitor__c com{get;set;}

       public gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c opflist{get;set;}

       public Id qId {get;set;}

       Public string all{get;set;}

//Declare a wrapper class  

       public class Wrapperclass{

 //custom wrapper datatype  

       Public string Name{get;set;}  
       Public string AccountType{get;set;}  
       Public date todaysDate{get;set;}  
       Public date Expected_Order_Date{get;set;}
       Public string Probability{get;set;}  
       Public string Internal_Comment{get;set;}  
       Public string External_Comment{get;set;}  

       Public string Segment{get;set;}  
       Public string Application{get;set;}  
       Public string Persona{get;set;}  
       Public string Geogrpahy{get;set;}  

       Public string PartNumbers{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal  Price{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal End_Customer_Price{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal Quantity {get;set;}  
       Public Decimal Total{get;set;}  

       Public string RFQ_justification{get;set;}  
       Public string Main_Customer_of_Account{get;set;}  
       Public string Bridgelux_competition_at_account{get;set;}
       Public string Geographic_regions_serviced{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_lighting_revenue{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_LED_revenue_or_percent{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_purchases_of_LED_light_sources{get;set;}
       Public string Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB{get;set;}  
       Public string Other_information{get;set;}  

       Public string Product_Series{get;set;}  
       Public string Volume{get;set;} 
       Public string Date_Price_is_Valid{get;set;} 

       Public string gmod_Opportunity{get;set;}
       Public string gmod_Product{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Quantity{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Price{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Quarter{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Month{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Amount{get;set;}
       Public Decimal Actual_Price{get;set;}
       Public Decimal  gmod_Year{get;set;}
       Public Date gmod_date{get;set;}
       Public string gmod_Month_Text{get;set;}
       Public Date  Forecast_Date{get;set;}




       Public wrapperClass(){} 

  }

       Public QuoteContentController(){}

       Public QuoteContentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

       qId=Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('Id');


    }

       Public Integer subtotalofquantity{get;set;}

       Public Integer subtotalofamount{get;set;}


     //  Public Integer quarter1subtotal{get;set;} 

    //   Public Integer amount1subtotal{get;set;} 

    //  Public Integer quarter2subtotal{get;set;} 

   //    Public Integer amount2subtotal{get;set;} 

   //    Public Integer quarter3subtotal{get;set;} 

  //     Public Integer amount3subtotal{get;set;} 

  //     Public Integer quarter4subtotal{get;set;} 

  //     Public Integer amount4subtotal{get;set;} 


       Public List<wrapperClass> disp_list {get;set;}{

       subtotalofquantity=0;

       subtotalofamount=0;

     /*  quarter1subtotal=0;

       amount1subtotal=0;

       quarter2subtotal=0;

       amount2subtotal=0;

       quarter3subtotal=0;

       amount3subtotal=0;

       quarter4subtotal=0;

       amount4subtotal=0; */

      /*  Integer quarter1subtotalTemp=0;

        Integer  amount1subtotalTemp=0;

        Integer quarter2subtotalTemp=0;

        Integer  amount2subtotalTemp=0;

        Integer quarter3subtotalTemp=0;

        Integer  amount3subtotalTemp=0;

        Integer quarter4subtotalTemp=0;

        Integer  amount4subtotalTemp=0;*/

      // Integer tempsubtotalofquantity=0;

     //  Integer tempsubtotalofamount=0;

      //define constructor to instantiate the wrapper data type 

       disp_list=new list<wrapperclass>();

     //Query all the list 

     list<Quote> q =[select id ,Name ,QuoteNumber,Effective_Date__c ,Comments__c ,Quote.Opportunity.id, 
                    Quote.Opportunity.Probability ,Quote.Opportunity.AccSegment__c ,Quote.Opportunity.AccApplication__c,Quote.Opportunity.Persona__c,Quote.Opportunity.Region__c
                    from Quote where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];

     Opportunity opp =[select id , Name, (select id, Quantity, product2id from OpportunityLineItems), probability, AccSegment__c from Opportunity where opportunity.Id =:q[0].opportunity.id];

    list<gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c>  opflist = [Select id ,Name ,gmod__opportunity__r.id,gmod__Quantity__c,gmod__Price__c , gmod__Month__c,    gmod__date__c,  gmod__Quarter__c ,gmod__Amount__c ,Actual_Price__c ,gmod__Year__c ,gmod__Month_Text__c ,Forecast_Date__c,gmod__Product__r.Name ,gmod__opportunity__r.name from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c WHERE gmod__Product__c!=null and gmod__opportunity__r.id =:opp.id Order BY gmod__Year__c, gmod__Month__c asc]; 

  //Iterate through each list to extract the values and add it to the custom wrapper data type  


        PartMap = new Map<String,Decimal>();

      //  PartMapQuantity = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Quarter1 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Quarter2 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Quarter3 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Quarter4 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Amount1 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Amount2= new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Amount3 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Amount4 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        for(gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c oppforecast : opflist)
        {

             if(oppforecast .gmod__Month_Text__c=='Jan' || oppforecast .gmod__Month_Text__c=='Feb'|| oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Mar'  )

                   {
                       if(Quarter1.containskey(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name ))
                             {
                                  Quarter1.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Quarter1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);             
                                  Amount1.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Amount1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
                                  //PartMap.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__c,PartMap.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__c) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                                 // PartMap.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__c,PartMap.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__c) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);  
                              }
                        else
                              {

                                 Quarter1.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                                 Amount1.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
                                // PartMap.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__c, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                                // PartMap.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__c,oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);

                                 wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();

                                 w.gmod_Opportunity = oppforecast.gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;

                                 w.gmod_Product = oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name;

                                 w.gmod_Quantity =oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c;

                                 w.gmod_Price=oppforecast.gmod__Price__c;

                                 w.Name =oppforecast.Name;

                                 w.gmod_Quarter=oppforecast.gmod__Quarter__c;

                                 w.gmod_Month=oppforecast.gmod__Month__c;

                                 w.gmod_Amount=oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c;

                                 w.Actual_Price=oppforecast.Actual_Price__c;

                                 w.gmod_Year=oppforecast.gmod__Year__c;

                                 w.gmod_date=oppforecast.gmod__date__c;

                                 w.gmod_Month_Text=oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c;

                                 w.Forecast_Date=oppforecast.Forecast_Date__c;

                                 disp_list.add(w);
                            } 
                         }

                 if(oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Apr' ||oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='May'|| oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='June')

                          {

                               if(Quarter2.containskey(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name))
                                       {
                                           Quarter2.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Quarter2.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);             
                                           Amount2.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Amount2.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
                                        }
                              else
                                         {

                                            Quarter2.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                                            Amount2.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);



                                        }
                           }
                 if(oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Jul' || oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Aug'|| oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Sept')

                        {

                              if(Quarter3.containskey(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name))
                                      {
                                          Quarter3.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Quarter3.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);             
                                          Amount3.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Amount3.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
                                       }
                             else
                                       {

                                          Quarter3.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                                          Amount3.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);



                                    }
                            }
             if(oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Oct' || oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Nov'|| oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Dec')
                      {
                          if(Quarter4.containskey(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name))
                             {
                                      Quarter4.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Quarter4.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);             
                                      Amount4.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Amount4.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
                             }
                     else
                             {

                                      Quarter4.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                                      Amount4.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);


                            }

                   }


        for (Quote qt :q){
             System.debug('Quote Size ++ '+q.size());
             System.debug('opp forcast ++ ' +opflist.size());

            for(integer i=0;i<opflist.size();i++){

            if(i==3){


            subtotalofquantity+= integer.valueOf(opflist[0].gmod__Quantity__c);

            subtotalofquantity+= integer.valueOf(opflist[1].gmod__Quantity__c);

            subtotalofquantity+= integer.valueOf(opflist[2].gmod__Quantity__c);

             subtotalofamount+= integer.valueOf(opflist[0]. gmod__Amount__c);
              subtotalofamount+= integer.valueOf(opflist[1]. gmod__Amount__c);
               subtotalofamount+= integer.valueOf(opflist[2]. gmod__Amount__c);

               System.debug('qty@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ++ ' + subtotalofquantity);

          System.debug('amt############# ++ ' +subtotalofamount);
}
          //  subtotalofquantity+= integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);

           // subtotalofquantity = tempsubtotalofquantity;

           //  subtotalofamount+= integer.valueOf(opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c);

            //subtotalofamount =tempsubtotalofamount;

           //  System.debug('qty@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ++ ' + subtotalofquantity);

       //   System.debug('amt############# ++ ' +subtotalofamount);

            /* Integer quarter1subtotalTemp = Integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);

            quarter1subtotal+=quarter1subtotalTemp;*/

           /* quarter1subtotalTemp+=Integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);

            quarter1subtotal=quarter1subtotalTemp;

            amount1subtotalTemp+= Integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Amount__c);

           amount1subtotal=amount1subtotalTemp; 


            System.debug('Qty%%%%%%%%%%% ++ ' +quarter1subtotal);

             System.debug('amt############# ++ ' +amount1subtotal);

             quarter2subtotalTemp+=Integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);

            quarter2subtotal=quarter2subtotalTemp;

            amount2subtotalTemp+=Integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Amount__c);

           amount2subtotal=amount2subtotalTemp;

            System.debug('Qty2$$$$$$$$$ ++ ' +quarter2subtotal);

             System.debug('amt2!!!!!!!!!!! ++ ' +amount2subtotal);

             quarter3subtotalTemp+=Integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);

            quarter3subtotal=quarter3subtotalTemp;

            amount3subtotalTemp+=Integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Amount__c);

           amount3subtotal=amount3subtotalTemp;

            System.debug('Qty3^^^^^ ++ ' +quarter3subtotal);

             System.debug('amt3&&&&&&& ++ ' +amount3subtotal);

             quarter4subtotalTemp+=Integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);

            quarter4subtotal=quarter3subtotalTemp;

            amount4subtotalTemp+=Integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Amount__c);

           amount4subtotal=amount4subtotalTemp;

            System.debug('Qty4******* ++ ' +quarter4subtotal);

             System.debug('amt4@@@@@@@@ ++ ' +amount4subtotal); */




                                        //Instantiating the wrapper SObject 

                                        wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();


                    //Assigning the wrapper variables from the SObject Fields in the database. 

                 w.gmod_Opportunity = opflist[i].gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;

                 w.gmod_Product = opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name;

                 w.gmod_Quantity =opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

                 w.gmod_Price=opflist[i].gmod__Price__c;

                 w.Name =opflist[i].Name;

                 w.gmod_Quarter=opflist[i].gmod__Quarter__c;

                 w.gmod_Month=opflist[i].gmod__Month__c;

                 w.gmod_Amount=opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c;

                 w.Actual_Price=opflist[i].Actual_Price__c;

                 w.gmod_Year=opflist[i].gmod__Year__c;

                 w.gmod_date=opflist[i].gmod__date__c;

                 w.gmod_Month_Text=opflist[i].gmod__Month_Text__c;

                 w.Forecast_Date=opflist[i].Forecast_Date__c; 


                              //Adding everthing to the List  


                            // w.name =qt.name;

                           //   disp_list.add(w);

                              // return disp_list;  
}

}
              }       
              }
         } //End of Class
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Row count in a visual force page pdf](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69551/row-count-in-a-visual-force-page-pdf)

Comment: @crmprogdev:In this query im looking for column count ,whereas the Row count got resolved.

Comment: Are you saying you can't figure out how many `<td>`'s you have in your table for the 1st `<tr>`?

Comment: @crmprogdev :In the table  the  subtotal count for all the quarters is not   not getting calculated correctly.For example in the above given table for the Quarter1 the column count is displayed as 300 ,where as in the visual force pae the Quarter1 column count is displaying incorrect.So seeing for an help to get the column values displayed correctly for all the quarters.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: @crmprogdev:PFA Screen shot of the table.

Comment: This is the same issue I pointed out to you in my answer to http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68072/display-total-below-the-table-in-visualforce-page-in-pdf-format/68263#68263

Comment: @crmprogdev:the subtotalofquantity and subtotalofamount not the fields .As mentioned in the repeat i have the wrapper called.I didnt get the for loop point.can u precisely explain or any example related to it will be help.

Comment: You're going to need to post your wrapper class for me to help in more detail. You need to calculate the column subtotals (there should be 4 of them) which need different var names that get calculated by summing values in the same Quarter (for each Quarter Q1 - Q4) by column that includes the values for each Opp name. From the code that's visible, I can't tell what's what. The subtotals by row are calculated differently than by column. That's what I was noting at the end of the post I referenced in final comments below.

Comment: @crmprogdev :I have updated the code completely.The column needs to be calculated based on the quarter and the product code for the year.

Answer (score 0):

Am confident there are many ways to optimize what's below. Will leave that to you. In any case, for your situation, here's what I would suggest is likely the easiest way for you to get the numbers you're looking for:

```
    integer Qrtr1QtyGrndTtl =  0;
    integer Qrtr2QtyGrndTtl =  0;
    integer Qrtr3QtyGrndTtl =  0;
    integer Qrtr4QtyGrndTtl =  0;
    list<integer>QtyGrndTtl = new list<integer>();

    decimal Qrtr1AmtGrndTtl =  0;
    decimal Qrtr2AmtGrndTtl =  0;
    decimal Qrtr3AmtGrndTtl =  0;
    decimal Qrtr4AmtGrndTtl =  0;
    list<decimal>AmtGrndTtl = new list<decimal>();  

For(Year Yr: opflist.gmod__Year__c){ 
// could simply replace this with for(j=0, j<3, j++)
// but am showing what it represents and have assumed gmod__Year__c 
// is a year and not text. Adjust code accordingly.

    integer j = 0;

    // replace oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name[i] with the product name string
    Integer Qty01 = Quarter1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name1);
    Integer Qty02 = Quarter2.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name1);
    Integer Qty03 = Quarter3.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name1);
    Integer Qty04 = Quarter4.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name1);
    Integer Qty11 = Quarter1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name2);
    Integer Qty12 = Quarter2.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name2);
    Integer Qty13 = Quarter3.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name2);
    Integer Qty14 = Quarter4.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name2);
    Integer Qty21 = Quarter1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name3);
    Integer Qty22 = Quarter2.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name3);
    Integer Qty23 = Quarter3.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name3);
    Integer Qty24 = Quarter4.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name3);

    Qrtr1QtyGrndTtl = 0 + Qty01 + Qty11 + Qty21; //reset to zero each yr.
    Qrtr2QtyGrndTtl = 0 + Qty02 + Qty12 + Qty22;
    Qrtr3QtyGrndTtl = 0 + Qty03 + Qty13 + Qty23;
    Qrtr4QtyGrndTtl = 0 + Qty04 + Qty14 + Qty24;
    QtyGrndTtl[j] = Qrtr1QtyGrndTtl + Qrtr2QtyGrndTtl + Qrtr3QtyGrndTtl + Qrtr4QtyGrndTtl;

    // replace oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name[i] with the product name string
    decimal amt01 = Amount1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name1);
    decimal amt02 = Amount1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name1);
    decimal amt03 = Amount1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name1);
    decimal amt04 = Amount1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name1);
    decimal amt11 = Amount1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name2);
    decimal amt12 = Amount1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name2);
    decimal amt13 = Amount1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name2);
    decimal amt14 = Amount1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name2);
    decimal amt21 = Amount1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name3);
    decimal amt22 = Amount1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name3);
    decimal amt23 = Amount1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name3);
    decimal amt24 = Amount1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name3);

    Qrtr1AmtGrndTtl = 0 + amt01 + amt11 + amt21; //reset to zero each yr.
    Qrtr2AmtGrndTtl = 0 + amt02 + amt12 + amt22;
    Qrtr3AmtGrndTtl = 0 + amt03 + amt13 + amt23;
    Qrtr4AmtGrndTtl = 0 + amt04 + amt14 + amt24;
    AmtGrndTtl[j] = Qrtr1AmtGrndTtl + Qrtr2AmtGrndTtl + Qrtr3AmtGrndTtl + Qrtr4AmtGrndTtl;

    j++;

}

Decimal GrndAmtGrndTtl = AmtGrndTtl[0] + AmtGrndTtl[1] + AmtGrndTtl[2];
Integer GrndQtyGrndTtl = QtyGrndTtl[0] + QtyGrndTtl[1] + QtyGrndTtl[2];
```

These last Grand Totals should match the Grand Totals you came up with using your row method.

**Edit:**

Below is your existing code with the commented portions removed. I have made notes as appropropriate which I hope you will understand.

```
public with sharing class QuoteContentController {

    //### For the vast majority of these you are only setting and 
    //### do not need to declare a getter method!

    public Map<String,Decimal> PartMap{get;set;}
    public Map<string,Decimal> Quarter1{get;set;}
    public Map<string,Decimal> Quarter2{get;set;}
    public Map<string,Decimal> Quarter3{get;set;}
    public Map<string,Decimal> Quarter4{get;set;}
    public Map<string,Decimal> Amount1{get;set;}
    public Map<string,Decimal> Amount2{get;set;}
    public Map<string,Decimal> Amount3{get;set;}
    public Map<string,Decimal> Amount4{get;set;}
    public Competitor__c com{get;set;}
    public gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c opflist{get;set;}
    public Id qId {get;set;}
    Public string all{get;set;}

    //Declare a wrapper class  

    public class Wrapperclass
    {

    //custom wrapper datatype  

    //### Again, unless you are reading these from your VF page, you only
    //### need to set their values. You do not need to "get" them!

    Public string Name{get;set;}  
    Public string AccountType{get;set;}  
    Public date todaysDate{get;set;}  
    Public date Expected_Order_Date{get;set;}
    Public string Probability{get;set;}  
    Public string Internal_Comment{get;set;}  
    Public string External_Comment{get;set;}  

    Public string Segment{get;set;}  
    Public string Application{get;set;}  
    Public string Persona{get;set;}  
    Public string Geogrpahy{get;set;}  

    Public string PartNumbers{get;set;}  
    Public Decimal Price{get;set;}  
    Public Decimal End_Customer_Price{get;set;}  
    Public Decimal Quantity {get;set;}  
    Public Decimal Total{get;set;}  

    Public string RFQ_justification{get;set;}  
    Public string Main_Customer_of_Account{get;set;}  
    Public string Bridgelux_competition_at_account{get;set;}
    Public string Geographic_regions_serviced{get;set;}  
    Public string Annual_lighting_revenue{get;set;}  
    Public string Annual_LED_revenue_or_percent{get;set;}  
    Public string Annual_purchases_of_LED_light_sources{get;set;}
    Public string Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB{get;set;}  
    Public string Other_information{get;set;}  

    Public string Product_Series{get;set;}  
    Public string Volume{get;set;} 
    Public string Date_Price_is_Valid{get;set;} 

    Public string gmod_Opportunity{get;set;}
    Public string gmod_Product{get;set;}
    Public Decimal gmod_Quantity{get;set;}
    Public Decimal gmod_Price{get;set;}
    Public Decimal gmod_Quarter{get;set;}
    Public Decimal gmod_Month{get;set;}
    Public Decimal gmod_Amount{get;set;}
    Public Decimal Actual_Price{get;set;}
    Public Decimal  gmod_Year{get;set;}
    Public Date gmod_date{get;set;}
    Public string gmod_Month_Text{get;set;}
    Public Date  Forecast_Date{get;set;}

    Public wrapperClass(){} 

    }

    Public QuoteContentController(){}

    Public QuoteContentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {

    qId=Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('Id');

    }

    Public Integer subtotalofquantity{set;}
    Public Integer subtotalofamount{set;}
    Public List<wrapperClass> disp_list {get;set;}{
    subtotalofquantity=0;
    subtotalofamount=0;

    disp_list=new list<wrapperclass>();

    //Query all the list 

    list<Quote> q =[select id ,Name ,QuoteNumber,Effective_Date__c ,Comments__c ,Quote.Opportunity.id, 
                Quote.Opportunity.Probability ,Quote.Opportunity.AccSegment__c ,Quote.Opportunity.AccApplication__c,Quote.Opportunity.Persona__c,Quote.Opportunity.Region__c
                from Quote where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];

    Opportunity opp =[select id , Name, (select id, Quantity, product2id from OpportunityLineItems), probability, AccSegment__c from Opportunity where opportunity.Id =:q[0].opportunity.id];

    list<gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c>  opflist = [Select id ,Name ,gmod__opportunity__r.id,gmod__Quantity__c,gmod__Price__c , gmod__Month__c,    gmod__date__c,  gmod__Quarter__c ,gmod__Amount__c ,Actual_Price__c ,gmod__Year__c ,gmod__Month_Text__c ,Forecast_Date__c,gmod__Product__r.Name ,gmod__opportunity__r.name from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c WHERE gmod__Product__c!=null and gmod__opportunity__r.id =:opp.id Order BY gmod__Year__c, gmod__Month__c asc]; 

    //Iterate through each list to extract the values and add it to the custom wrapper data type  

    PartMap = new Map<String,Decimal>();

    //  PartMapQuantity = new Map<String,Decimal>();

    //### Here's the source of the problem with your quarterly data.  
    //### The same variables are used for each of your years. 

    Quarter1 = new Map<String,Decimal>();
    Quarter2 = new Map<String,Decimal>();
    Quarter3 = new Map<String,Decimal>();
    Quarter4 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

    Amount1 = new Map<String,Decimal>();
    Amount2 = new Map<String,Decimal>();
    Amount3 = new Map<String,Decimal>();
    Amount4 = new Map<String,Decimal>();


//### One possibility would have been to create a For loop here that would
//### operated on For(Year yr:opflist.gmod__Year__c) or the number value of it
//### In that way, all of your data that was year dependent could have been
//### calculated in the same loop. If statements could have been added to 
//### sort or separate your data by year (yes, I know your query did an order by) 


    //### Had you looped on the year, you could then have added an if statement
    //### here that would have sorted your data into separate years for you and
    //### you wouldn't be having the problem of not knowing which year it comes from 
    //### It could either be put into separate maps or separate wrappers for each year.

    for(gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c oppforecast : opflist)
    {

        if(oppforecast .gmod__Month_Text__c=='Jan' || oppforecast .gmod__Month_Text__c=='Feb'|| oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Mar'  )
        {
            if(Quarter1.containskey(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name ))
            {
                Quarter1.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Quarter1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);             
                Amount1.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Amount1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
            }
            else
            {

                Quarter1.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                Amount1.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
                wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();

                w.gmod_Opportunity = oppforecast.gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;

                w.gmod_Product = oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name;

                w.gmod_Quantity =oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c;

                w.gmod_Price=oppforecast.gmod__Price__c;

                w.Name =oppforecast.Name;

                w.gmod_Quarter=oppforecast.gmod__Quarter__c;

                w.gmod_Month=oppforecast.gmod__Month__c;

                w.gmod_Amount=oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c;

                w.Actual_Price=oppforecast.Actual_Price__c;

                w.gmod_Year=oppforecast.gmod__Year__c;

                w.gmod_date=oppforecast.gmod__date__c;

                w.gmod_Month_Text=oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c;

                w.Forecast_Date=oppforecast.Forecast_Date__c;

                disp_list.add(w);
            } 
        }

        if(oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Apr' ||oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='May'|| oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='June')
        {

            if(Quarter2.containskey(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name))
            {
                Quarter2.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Quarter2.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);             
                Amount2.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Amount2.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
            }else{
                Quarter2.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                Amount2.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);

            }
        }
        if(oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Jul' || oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Aug'|| oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Sept')
        {

            if(Quarter3.containskey(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name))
            {
                Quarter3.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Quarter3.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);             
                Amount3.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Amount3.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
            }else{
                Quarter3.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                Amount3.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);

            }
        }
        if(oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Oct' || oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Nov'|| oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Dec')
        {
            if(Quarter4.containskey(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name))
            {
                Quarter4.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Quarter4.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);             
                Amount4.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Amount4.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);

            }else{

                Quarter4.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                Amount4.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);

            }

        }

        for (Quote qt :q)
        {
            System.debug('Quote Size ++ '+q.size());
            System.debug('opp forcast ++ ' +opflist.size());

            for(integer i=0;i<opflist.size();i++)
            {

            //### Is this perhaps where you added the code that I wrote?
            //### Lines like this: Qrtr2QtyGrndTtl = 0 + Qty02 + Qty12 + Qty22;
            //### in the code I wrote require that all 3 yrs of data be 
            //### present when the code is run and therefore cannot run inside
            //### of this loop or the oppforecast : opflist loop! It needs
            //### to be run entirely outside of the oppforecast : opflist
            //### loop once all of the data has been processed unless you 
            //### hold the quarterly data in temp variables of some kind

                if(i==3){

                    subtotalofquantity+= integer.valueOf(opflist[0].gmod__Quantity__c);
                    subtotalofquantity+= integer.valueOf(opflist[1].gmod__Quantity__c);
                    subtotalofquantity+= integer.valueOf(opflist[2].gmod__Quantity__c);

                    subtotalofamount+= integer.valueOf(opflist[0]. gmod__Amount__c);
                    subtotalofamount+= integer.valueOf(opflist[1]. gmod__Amount__c);
                    subtotalofamount+= integer.valueOf(opflist[2]. gmod__Amount__c);

                    System.debug('qty@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ++ ' + subtotalofquantity);

                    System.debug('amt############# ++ ' +subtotalofamount);
                }

                //Instantiating the wrapper SObject 

                wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();

                //Assigning the wrapper variables from the SObject Fields in the database. 

                w.gmod_Opportunity = opflist[i].gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;

                w.gmod_Product = opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name;

                w.gmod_Quantity =opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

                w.gmod_Price=opflist[i].gmod__Price__c;

                w.Name =opflist[i].Name;

                w.gmod_Quarter=opflist[i].gmod__Quarter__c;

                w.gmod_Month=opflist[i].gmod__Month__c;

                w.gmod_Amount=opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c;

                w.Actual_Price=opflist[i].Actual_Price__c;

                w.gmod_Year=opflist[i].gmod__Year__c;

                w.gmod_date=opflist[i].gmod__date__c;

                w.gmod_Month_Text=opflist[i].gmod__Month_Text__c;

                w.Forecast_Date=opflist[i].Forecast_Date__c; 

                // w.name =qt.name;

            } // end for(integer i=0;i<opflist.size();i++)
        } // end for (Quote qt :q)
    } // end for(gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c oppforecast : opflist)       
    } // end Public List<wrapperClass> disp_list {get;set;}
} //End of Class
```

I hope the above comments in your code help clarify what I've been attempting to explain. As an aside, this is likely also the issue you're having with adding data at a later time. Both the new and old data isn't being associated with a year that you can iterate on using repeats when generating your page.

I don't know of any other way to try and explain this to you. You're going to need to sit down and work with your code, the relevant docs and begin thinking things through logically in order to sort this through from here. Its the only way you're going to learn to do this for yourself.

Comment: :Thanks for your reply.Necessary changes made.But i get an Error as :System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Class.QuoteContentController.<init>: line 433, column 1.The line is Qrtr2QtyGrndTtl = 0 + Qty02 + Qty12 + Qty22;

Comment: That would indicate that one of the instances of your map `Quarter2.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name[i])` is returning a null value. You'll need to add code to trap each of those to return a value of zero if as opposed to null. I'm sure you have the same issue elsewhere and have handled it in some manner.

Comment: @ crmprogdev:I tried adding the debug logs for all the variables .Except for Qty01, Qty11, Qty21 all the variable value is displaying as Null.But their do have the data. The month ,product name data is getting displayed as "JAN",BXRC-25E4000-F-04 for all the variables.

Comment: Did you insert the code I provided after you've gotten data for each quarter for all of your years? Do those variables still exist once you've done that? That's one thing which troubles me about your code. It doesn't appear as though you have a For loop on `opflist.gmod__Year__c` when collecting it. Instead it appears as though you do it only for a year (couldn't tell for certain). It's entirely possible the data no longer exists for each of the 3 years unless you've saved in a variable by Year. See my comments about looping in Display Total Below the Table in Visualforce page in PDF Format

Comment: :I have not used the for loop of year.I have started from for(j=0, j<3, j++).

Comment: See my edited response above. Be sure to read comments in code marked with `//###`.

Comment: @ crmprogdev:Thanks for your reply.As per the suggestion i have declared the map for  Year,i added in the if statement { Year.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Year.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) +oppforecast.gmod__Year__c);}.The for(j=0, j<3, j++) i have used outside the opplist . when i checked  in the debug logs for the Quarter1 it gets added thrice for the same product code and get displayed in the total.But the o/p for the Quarter1 should be the total of different product codes present in that quarter should get added and displayed.